# How to organize mongodb database for a huge set of time-value pairs for a lot of documents?

Tags: mongodb

There is a set of registrators, say 100k. Every registrator 24 times a day gives value smth like `23.123`. I need to save this value and time. Then I need to **calculate how value changes for some period**, e.g. 4jun2014 - 19jul2014: In order to do this I have to find last value of 3jun2014 and last value of 19jul2014.

First I am trying to estimate size of data stored by one registrator. Time+value must be lower than 100 bytes. 1 year is < 100*24*365 = 720kB of data, so I can easily store 10 years of data (since 7.2M < 16M limit) at my document. I decided not to store registered data at `registeredData` collection but to store registrator data embedded in registrator object as a tree timedata->year->month->day:

```
{
    code: '3443-12',
    timedata: {
        2013: {
            6: {
                13: [
                    {t:1391345679, d:213.12},
                    {t:1391349679, d:213.14},
                ]
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So it is easy to get values of the day: just get `find({code: "3443-12"})[0].timedata[2013][6][13]`.

When I get new data, I just push it into array of existing document and it eventually grows from zero to 7Mb.

**Questions**

What is the stored size of `{t:1391345679, d:213.12}` line, is it less than 100bytes?

Is it right way to organize database for such purposes?

100k documents with 5Mb size = 500G. Does MongoDB deal fast with database size much more than RAM size?

**Update**

I decided to store time not as a timestamp but as time in seconds from the start of a day: 0 - 86399: `{t: 86123, d: 213.12}`.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's related to your schema design (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/). You will have to take into account document growth, reallocation and probably  you would like to preallocate documents unless you want all of them to grow at the same time at the beginning of each day

Comment: @EnriqueFueyo thanks, I can do preallocating once a month. In order to soften system load, adding of 24 data is performed at random hour of a day. But what is the size of my piece of data `{t:1391345679, d:213.12}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last question, " Does MongoDB deal fast with database size much more than RAM size?" the answer is it can, but it depends on a number of factors.

MongoDB works best when the working set fits within the memory available to MongoDB. When it does not you tend to see rather rapid performance declines. How big that working set is a function of database schema, indexes built and your data access patterns.

Let's say you have a years worth of data in your database, but regularly only touch the last few days of data. Then your working set is likely to be composed of the memory required to keep the last few days of data in memory, plus enough of the indexes in memory for you to properly update and read from them.

Alternatively, if you are randomly accessing data across a year and have high and update volume you may have a significantly larger working set to deal with.

As a point of comparison, I've got a production MongoDB instance that has around 500M documents in it, taking up around 2 TB of disk storage. Total memory on the primary of the replica set is 128GB (1/16th the total storage) and we're not experiencing any performance problems.

The key for all of it though is how much data do you access over time. The killer for MongoDB performance is memory contention, when you are paging out data to service a new request only to re-page that old data right back in. And it gets far worse if you cannot keep your indexes in memory.

Comment: Thanks. How can I estimate memory consumption?  Say, every request gets 100 documents with size of 1M (If I include log data into document). Its execution lasts 0.1sec. If I have 100 hits per second, I need 100*0.1 * 0.1G = 1G of memory to deal with documents. 100k registrators with a couple of indexes takes about 1k*100k=100M of memory. So I easily can use 16G of memory to handle 100 hits per second for my 100k documents if fetch them by its indexes. Right?

Comment: Your best approach here is to take a sample of data and load it into MongoDB. If you run db.collectionname.stats() you will see a fair amount of information including average object size and total index size for indexes on the collection. You can then use that data to construct what your working set probably should be - I'd start with being able to keep all indexes actively used in memory plus several minutes worth of data in memory. The time component is critical - it's not just how many docs you hit but how long do they need to stay resident?

Comment: John, so the only way is to load data and watch how mongo deals with it, right?

Comment: It was hard to decide, which answer is the best since both of them makes something clear.

Comment: Yes, the only real way to get an accurate idea is to benchmark ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it and it is less than 100 B, in deed, it is 48 B:

```
var num=100000;
for(i=0;i<num;i++){
  db.foo.insert({t:1391345679, d:213.12})
};
db.foo.stats().avgObjSize // => Outputs 48
```

Comment: Thanks+up. In addition I decided to organize data this way: `{t: 0-86399, d:213.12}`, so I just keep seconds from start of a day, not timestamp.

Comment: You store this data as a document, but I wish to store thousands of data at every document. Probably array of `[{t:1391345679, d:213.12}, {t:1391345679, d:213.12} ...]` has another size.

Comment: Well, you asked for the size of that line, but the for-loop could be easily modified to store the data in an array with lots of documents {t:,d:} (for example with a new inner for-loop) and see the avgObjSize

Comment: I just don't know how much extra information is stored in this 2 cases: 100k documents or one array with 100k data. Will try to upgrade my console skills to work it out by myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are doing is kind of a hack to avoid normalising your data (m.b. for transaction purposes?) and  sooner or later you may run into problems (e.g. requirements change, size of your data changes, new fields are introduced etc.) I do not know your schema and domain, but if you go with denomarmalized model as you are doing you must be sure that documents will not exceed the size limit of 16MB. That being said, I would recommend [schema design article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/).

Answers:

- The previous answer gives a hint about the document size. You can use it as a starting point.
- Choosing an effective data models depends on your application needs. The main question is the decision to denormalize or use linking. Note, generally with denormalized data you achieve better performance for read operations, as well as the ability to request and retrieve related data in a single database operation. Embedding makes it possible to update a document in a single atomic write operation (transactionally). So, when to use embedded (denormalized):

> > - you have “contains” relationships between entities. See Model
> >       One-to-One Relationships with Embedded Documents.
> > - you have one-to-many relationships between entities. In these relationships the “many” or
> >       child documents always appear with or are viewed in the context of the
> >       “one” or parent documents. See Model One-to-Many Relationships with
> >       Embedded Documents.

In your situation your documents will grow after creation which can impact write performance and lead to data fragmentation. You can control this with [padding factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-padding).
- About the performance: it depends on how you create your indexes. More importantly, on your access patterns. For each query executed often, check out the output from `explain()` to see how many documents have been checked.

Comment: Thanks. I just think that if I use another collection to save data from registrators, It will be like just common RDBMS and it takes a long time to fetch correspondent data. Say, to get registrator value change for 1jun-19jul I need to make 2 requests through a very large collection (~100k*24hours*365days*3years = 2G documents). But if I store data at registrator document, I need only one fetch by _id of document with size of 50bytes*24h*365d*3y = 1Mb. Am I wrong?

Comment: Mongodb is designed exactly to handle large collections. A typical use case for embedding (using 1 collection) is when you want to show the whole document to the user (for example in a webpage, lets say a book with an author). In your case, I would definitely consider two collections.

Comment: One of my cases is to show stats for one registrator. To get it from document I don't need any extra request. To get month data from another collection I need to search through two indexes (registrator_id and time). It must be more heavily.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan how often do you perform write on registrator? If very often, you can try to allocate each documents with the expected amount of space to ensure you have enough space. About performance: you need to check if you are hitting indexes. If not, make sure you create appropriate indexes.

Comment: twice a day for each one. Are you talking about factorOf2 option?